# Show the following is bounded in $n$ (and actually converges to $0$)

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Consider the sequence $$a_n:=\dfrac{n^{n+0.5}\left(\dfrac{n(n-2)}{2}-0.5n\log(n)\right)^{0.5n\log(n)}}{(n-s)^{n-s+0.5}\left(\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}-0.5n\log(n)\right)^{0.5n\log(n)}}$$

Show that $a_n\to0$ for any $s\leq \dfrac{n}{2}$.

I did some simulations and found that it does converge to $0$, however I can't think of any analytic proof of this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to simplify this expression a bit?

Comment: I'd try to look at the behaviour of numerator and denominator to see if L'Hôpital's theorem applies (looks like it).

Comment: L'Hopital's theorem doesn't work for sequences, you can try Stolz–Cesàro theorem but it seems unlikely it will work.

Comment: @user26977: you can view $n$ as a real variable, take the limit as $n \to \infty$ and use lHopital. No guarantees, but there is nothing here that forces $n$ to be natural

Comment: Is $s$ a constant? What does $s\le n/2$ mean?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Can I really use L'Hospital? I am a bit scared to use it, as things are so complicated. Would it be better if I can somehow show, for  sufficiently large n, the sequence $a_n$ is monotonic? At least I'd get a bound in that case!

Comment: @zhw. $s$ is not really a constant, but $s\leq n/2$ is taken so that things are well-defined. Probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u_n = 1/(n-1-\ln n).$ Then the expression equals

$$\frac{n^{n+1/2}}{(n-s)^{n-s+1/2}}[(1-u_n)^{1/u_n}]^{(u_nn\ln n)/2}.$$

The outer exponent is $\sim \ln n^{1/2}.$ Inside the brackets we have convergence to $1/e.$ The expression thus looks like

$$\frac{n^{n+1/2}}{(n-s)^{n-s+1/2}}n^{-1/2}$$

for large $n.$ If you allow $s$ to wander around subject only to $s\le n/2,$ there's no way to get convergence. For example, if we take $s=n/2,$ the above is

$$\frac{n^{n+1/2}}{(n/2)^{n/2+1/2}}n^{-1/2},$$

which blasts off to $\infty.$